# Increment/decrement integer in user model by 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model which has these columns - name, email, books_on_loan

I have a booking system where users can check out/in books. When A user checks a book out I want to increase their 'books_on_loan_ integer by one, and vice versa.

So far I have tried it like this and am getting an error "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass" - it doesnt like the @user.books_on_loan

```
def check_out

  @params = params[:book]
  title = @params[:title]
  name = @params[:name]
  @book = Book.find_by_title(title)
  @user = User.find_by_name(name)




 if @user == nil
   @note = 'This user is not registered.'
 elsif @book == nil
   @note = 'This book is not in the library.'
 elsif @book.onloan == 1
   @note = 'This book is on loan.'
 elsif @user.books_on_loan == 3
   @note = 'This user already has 3 books out.'

else
  @book.onloan = 1
  @book.save
  @books_loaned = BooksOnloan.create(book_id: @book.id, user_id: @user.id)
  @books_loaned.save
  @user.books_on_loan = @user.books_on_loan + 1
  @user.save
  @note = 'The book was checked out.'
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html    
  end    
end
```

Comment: User `@user.books_on_loan.to_i`, so that it converts **nil** to **0** when **books_on_loan** is nil for first time

Comment: You should *calculate* that value. If performance is an issue, use the built-in [`:counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@user.increment :books_on_loan, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with following codes, that will handle nil value for @user.books_on_loan

```
  @user.books_on_loan = @user.books_on_loan.to_i + 1
```

or

```
  @user.books_on_loan = (@user.books_on_loan || 0) + 1
```

or

```
  @user.books_on_loan = (@user.books_on_loan.present? ? @user.books_on_loan : 0)  + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

While most answers here are ok, you'd rather change the root of the problem **otherwise you'd have to use guard causes in your whole app.**

It seems `books_on_loan` to be an attribute in db, so do :

```
 change_column :users, :books_on_loan, :integer, default: 0
 #and change existing bad data
 User.update_all({books_on_loan: 0}, {books_on_loan: nil})
```

Or you could change the getter in your class:

```
def books_on_loan
  super || 0
end
```

---

Side note, design wise, its not that a good idea to have an integer in db maintaining the current books on loan: you could loose sync the real ones.

You'd rather count a real association.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `@user.books_on_loan.to_i`. The **to_i** will convert **nil** into **0** automatically

Answer (score 0):

ost answers are very correct but I'd like to add the following.

To answer your question, incrementing the value of an attribute (even on a variable that returns `nil`) can be done this way:

`@user.books_on_loan =+ 1`

decrementing being: `@user.books_on_loan =- 1`

However, you can leverage the benefit of proper model associations here and have a **has_many -> through** relationship between **User** and **Book** where by adding/removing a book for a user, the counter is adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides practical abstraction that you can use: `increment` and `decrement`.
So you could now do something like this:

```
@user.increment(:books_on_loan, 1)
```

Increment takes 2 argument. The table column and the number by which you increment. It initializes the attribute to zero if nil and adds the value passed as by (default is 1).

Similarly you can use

```
@user.decrement(:book_on_loan, 1)
```

More on this [HERE](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/decrement)